# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string - Python Formatting Issue

Tags: python, cmd

I'm trying to run a shell command from a python script file (myscipt.py). The command is

```
os.system('For /R "D:\SVN\fido\" %G IN (*.so) do "python timeout.py %G %s" ' %l)
```

This command will recursively search for all the `.so` files under D:\SVN\fido\ and each found `.so` file will become first argument `%G` of the python script timeout.py. I need to pass an integer value as second argument to this timeout.py file, for that purpose i am trying to run the above shown command.

The value of l is an integer value and i need to pass this value as second argument of this timeout.py file. When i run this command i am getting "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string" error.

Any sugessions? It should be a python formatting issue. According to me the `%s` should be replaced by the integer value of `l` but i do not know why is it  giving error. Below is myscript.py file that i am using.

```
import sys
import os
l=int(23410000)

print l


os.system('For /R "D:\SVN\fido\" %G IN (*.so) do "python timeout.py %G %s" ' %l)
```

Comment: I suppose you mean %G is part of your command to send to the os. Here python will "think" you want to insert one value per % whatever, hence 3 values. It finds only one. You probably should the % in %G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, based on the error message, is that the python interpreter thinks this format string should receive more arguments, because to the `%G` looks like a placeholder.

To fix it: replace each `%G`with `%%G`, the %% will be interpreted as a literal representation of the percent sign and not a placeholder prefix.

FYI: to replace an int you would usually use `%d` ( and `%f` for floating point values and for all the details -> [string formating 101](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting))

Comment: Yes its working now. %%G is right option here. Thanks